# Cubeset Formula for Unique List from Two Expressions

Tags: excel, formula

I'm stumped trying to find a solution for getting a list of non-duplicate brands from separate months with the formula below.  This formula works but it combines all the Brands from Month1 and Month2 in a complete list including duplicates.  I'm trying to get a unique list of brands that appear in either Month1 or Month2. I've tried the '+' and ":" in place of the comma between the Month1 & Month2 expressions but not luck.  I appreciate any insight!

- Working formula below returns duplicates when using a CubeRankedMember to
  pull in the data

---

```
CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","({[Programs].[Months].[Month1],[Programs].[Months].[Month2]},([Programs].[Division].[Division1],[Programs].[Brand].Children))","Brands",3)
```

Comment: imho : add another helper column, in both month. do countif() for both month brands column, and take only those with countif() =1. Then combine both list in another sheet.

Comment: This isn't an option for me since there are many different months that can be chosen in the data (user selections determine).  I'm using cube formulas to pull data out of a data model, not a spreadsheet.  I appreciate the reply.